# Python sequence multi-threading for network tasks

Tags: python, multithreading

I am trying to run a script with multiple threads to decrease the time taken by the script to complete. 
I need to know how to implement multithreading in a program like this.

Script example :

```
def getnetworkdata():
   data = ["somesite.com/1", "somesite.com/2", "somesite.com/3", "somesite.com/4"]
   for url in data:
      r = requests.get(url)
      someOtherArray.append(r.text)
```

Threads should be running in sequence for the required task.

The output I am expecting :

```
someOtherArray = [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

I am using Python 2.x

Comment: And your question will be...?

Comment: Okey...Have you read about Multithreading in Python Doc..?

Comment: @IronFist yes but I wasn't quite able to implement it in this way.

Comment: You mean like having each thread dealing with each `somesite` from `data` list?

Comment: Yes, I want to do it in a sequence. The sequence should not break. The final array should contain data in the correct sequence. @IronFist

Comment: If you want it in sequence then why you need multi-threading anyway?

Comment: One option that come to my mind is to start every thread all at once. Each thread not only retrieves the data but also keeps the sequence number. The main thread waits until all threads have finished. And then it gets the data from the subthreads according to their sequence number. Not sure if I've explained myself...

Answer (score 1):

```
from multiprocessing.dummy import Pool as ThreadPool

data = ["somesite.com/1", "somesite.com/2", "somesite.com/3", "somesite.com/4"]

# Make the Pool of workers
pool = ThreadPool(4)

# Open the urls in their own threads
# and return the results
results = pool.map(requests.get, data)

someOtherArray = map( lambda x: x.text, results )

#close the pool and wait for the work to finish 
pool.close()
pool.join()
```